# Jenkins pipeline job execution

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I cannot execute following script in Jenkins console, I am getting

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   Script1.node() is applicable for argument types:
>   (Script1$_run_closure1) values: [Script1$_run_closure1@2a2abfa]

```
node {
        stage('Lancement: Automate_IPI_CHECK'){
        try {
               bat ('C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\CScript.exe ' + 
               "D:\\AUT_IPI_CHECK\\Scripts\\runnerInjecteur.vbs " +User +" "+ 
                 Pwd +" "                                                                                           +' \CheminJenkins:'+ TestSet
                                                                                                  +' \RepLog:' + RepLog)
         } catch(err) {
                  echo err.getMessage();
          }
        };
```

If I execute this, it Throw exception

```
node {
        stage('Lancement: Automate_IPI_CHECK'){
              try {
                     bat ('C:/Windows/SysWOW64/CScript.exe ' + "D:/AUT_IPI_CHECK/Scripts/runnerInjecteur.vbs " + User +" "+ Pwd +" "
                                                                                                  +' /CheminJenkins:'+ TestSet
                                                                                                  +' /RepLog:' + RepLog)
              } catch(err) 
              {
                      echo err.getMessage();
              }
        };
}
```

Please help me

Comment: Maybe you just don't have pipeline plugin...

Comment: Thanks daggett, I' m going to check if the pipeline plugin is installed.